# Tridion Project GetJvmLoader Error

Tags: 2011, content-delivery

I am new to Tridion Integration, my project was already developed when I run from my local machine I got  following error. plz help me out what cause this error?

> Exception Occured    at Codemesh.JuggerNET.NativeInterface.GetJvmLoader(Int32 ctorVersion, String configFile, String vers, String conf, String reserved, Boolean bEnvOverrides, Boolean bDefaultJvm, Int32 traceFacility, Int32 traceLevel, Int32& error)

Sometimes I am getting below error also.

> Unable to load DLL 'xmogrt': The specified module could not be found. 
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Comment: In addition you might want to do a search for "tridion xmogrt.dll", as this has been asked before. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13918310/unable-to-load-dll-xmogrt-from-tridion-metadata-query

Answer (score 1):

This error generally occurs due to the Tridion's `xmogrt` DLL.

You should check that the DLL is present and should be 32-bit version if your machine is 32-bit or 64-bit version if your machine is 64-bit.

There could be many other reasons and you may want to refer this great question:

[Error while installing Tridion 2013 SP1 CDS: Unable to load DLL 'xmogrt'](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/4701/error-while-installing-tridion-2013-sp1-cds-unable-to-load-dll-xmogrt)