# Unable to load DLL 'xmogrt'

Tags: 2013-sp1, content-delivery, dxa, dxa-1.2

When I am trying setup DXA 1.2 version I am getting the below error.
I tried all possible solutions given by Tridion Stack exchange.

1. My OS is Windows 7 Enterprise 64 Bit.
2. JRE 1.8.0_144 version is installed.
3. Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable is installed.
4. Copied all required JARS and DLLS.
5. I have Valid CD License files.
6. I placed correct version of `netrtsn.dll` and `xmogrt.dll` in bin folder.

After doing all the above also I am getting below error.

> [DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'xmogrt': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)]
>      Codemesh.JuggerNET.NativeInterface.GetJvmLoader(Int32 ctorVersion, String configFile, String vers, String conf, String reserved, Boolean bEnvOverrides, Boolean bDefaultJvm, Int32 traceFacility, Int32 traceLevel, Int32& error) +0
>      Codemesh.JuggerNET.JvmLoader.GetJvmLoader(Boolean bEnvOverrides, Boolean bDefaultJvm, TraceFacility fac, TraceLevel level) +138
>      Codemesh.JuggerNET.JvmLoader.GetJvmLoader() +49
>      Codemesh.JuggerNET.NativeInterface.ToJavaStringPinning(String str, Int32 length, IntPtr& result) +69
>      Codemesh.JuggerNET.NativeInterface.ToJavaString(String str) +80
>      Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethodArguments.Add_string(String str) +153
>      Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethodArguments.Add(Object obj, Type type) +249
>      Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethodArguments.Add(Object obj) +44
>      Org.Slf4j.LoggerFactory.GetLogger(String name) +139
>      Tridion.ContentDelivery.Web.Utilities.Logger..ctor(String loggerName) +56
>      Tridion.ContentDelivery.Web.Utilities.LoggerFactory.GetLogger(String loggerName) +52
>      Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.HttpModule..cctor() +81

Then I tried solution mentioned in the following URL [Unable to load DLL 'xmogrt': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/4003/unable-to-load-dll-xmogrt-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found-exception)

Followed the instructions given in the answers removed `xmogrt.dll` and placed in `windows/SysWOW64`, Still same error.

When I placed xmogrt.dll in `windows/system32` the above error gone and now getting;

> Unable to locate a valid Tridion Home directory, see Tridion event log

No logs are generated.

Then I tried instructions given in the follwoing link [Getting Error message "Unable to locate a valid Tridion Home Directory" while accessing Contact Profilesync.aspx page](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/11901/getting-error-message-unable-to-locate-a-valid-tridion-home-directory-while-ac)

Still I am unable to resolve the error.

Same code base is working on other developer system.

What I am missing, Do we have any other options for resolving `xmogrt` DLL error.

Comment: Where did you get your xmogrt dll? If you had transferred it as a zip over network, make sure you unblock the zip property before extracting it. This is first guess.

Comment: Thank you for quick response, I downloaded from my project SVN

Comment: do you have proper access on bin folder? try giving everyone and then check. if works. then remove everyone and give access to App-pool identity user.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly still you are somewhere still not using right DLL versions, Try following steps to fix this issue.

- Uninstall to revert all your changes
- Install Java JRE 1.8 (x64) bit, type `java -version` in the command prompt to ensure Java is working as expected, try to restart system also double check is there any other Java version installed in the system find and remove
- Download and install the Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable (x64) bit
- To install a 64-bit .NET Web application, access the `x86_64\` In the installation media folder `Content Delivery\roles\api\DotNET` copy to the bin folder.
- For MS SQL Database required `sqljdbc42.jar` for Java 8 not `sqljdbc4.jar`

I hope it will resolve your issue.

Comment: Hi Velmurugan, Thank you for detailed instructions, After doing the above steps Still i am facing same issue, In other system I was able to execute the application and Assets are loading but page cannot be displayed error is coming after view rendering.

Answer (score 1):

Like the answer already given, I think it can only be something related to the `netrtsn.dll` and `xmogrt.dll` you are using. They are either blocked or not of the correct version is what I still suspect.

If you check out the first two answers of: [Error while installing Tridion 2013 SP1 CDS: Unable to load DLL 'xmogrt'](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/4701/error-while-installing-tridion-2013-sp1-cds-unable-to-load-dll-xmogrt) you see a few resolutions that can be helpful and should be checked. The other two answers given there can also be of help, but that is repeating what has already been answered here.

But most important to mention is that you should not place these DLLs in your `windows/SysWOW64` or `windows/System32` directories, they belong in the `bin` folder of your web application. Else you are creating a system global depoendency which will only be harder to solve, so please make sure they are deleted from the system folders before trying to solve it any further.

*note: If all else fails, maybe it is an option to consider upgrading to Web 8 and get rid of the whole in-process and JuggerNET trouble. SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 is nearing its end of support and we are currently on DXA 1.7, with the release date of DXA 2.0 nearing soon also ;o).*